# Cakephp - Checkbox names

Tags: php, cakephp

Currently, i have succeeded in creating the checkbox. 
The array which i have setup is as below:

```
$emailName = $this->User->find('list', array(
    'fields' => array('User.username', 'User.email')
    ));
```

The output is as follows:

```
array
  'admin' => string 'asd@asd.asd' (length=11)
  'test' => string 'test@test.test' (length=14)
  'Floo' => string 'XXXX@gmail.com' (length=16)
```

I'm trying to make the checkbox shows the username instead of the user email in view.ctp.

I have tried using the following code in view.ctp

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('Address_list.['.$emailName['username'].']', array(
    'type' => 'select',
    'multiple' => 'checkbox',
    'options' => $emailName['email']
    )); ?>
```

However, it seems that this doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: First, you're not following cake conversions. I'm assuming that "Address_list" is a made-up field. To make this work, simply remove the `[` and `]` from the field name and that should solve your problem.

Comment: Nope, tried removing it but doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not formatting your form field for the checkbox list correctly. Try changing it to this:

```
echo $this->Form->input('Address_list', array(
    'multiple' => 'checkbox',
    'options' => $emailName, 
));
```

However, this will return the value of Username based on the selection of Email the user chooses. It creates the form like this:

```
<label for="Address_list">Address List</label>
<input type="hidden" id="Address_list" value="" name="data[Address_list]"/>
<div class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="AddressListAdmin" value="admin" 
   name="data[Address_list][]"/><label for="AddressListAdmin">asd@example.com</label></div>
<div class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="AddressListTest" value="test"
   name="data[Address_list][]"/><label for="AddressListTest">test@example.com</label></div>
<div class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" id="AddressListFloo" value="Floo" 
   name="data[Address_list][]"/><label for="AddressListFloo">XXX@example.com</label></div>
```

Comment: Yes. this works.. To achieve what i want, i re-code the find method. so that email comes first and the name comes 2nd.